# How to find some question that I can perfect answer it?

Tags: discussion, answers

How to find some question that I can perfect answer it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but a perfect answer requires very good readability. Specifically with regards to English grammar, as non-native speakers, and there are a lot of those visiting these pages, often have trouble making sense of ungrammatical posts (such as yours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To more easily find questions that you would be able to answer, you may look for the *tags* associated with the topics that you are interested in and know something about, or that you would like to know more about by reading questions and answers written by others.

You can search for a particular tag using `[tagname]` in the search box, e.g. [`[posix] substitution`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bposix%5D+substitution) if you want to search for things tagged with `posix` and containing the word `substitution`.

You may also automatically get certain questions highlighted or dimmed on the main page by adding "favorite" and "ignored" tags. Just click "edit" after "Favorite Tags" on the right hand side pane of the main page.

Comment: It's astonishing, but in the last year and a half I never actually noticed the highlighting on questions tagged with my "favorite tags" before.  Thanks for pointing it out!  :)